# How to create public and private key with openssl?

Tags: openssl, rsa, digital-signature, saml

My questions are

- How to create

  - a public key
  - and private key with OpenSSL in windows?
- How to put the created public key

  - in `.crt` file and
  - the private one in `.pcks8` file

I want to use these two keys to sign a SAML assertion in Java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. A certificate (what you usually store in a `.crt` file) contains a public key, but a public key in itself is not a certificate

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  i'm trying to create a credential in opensaml-j and this latter requires a public key and private key in order to use this credential in a signature

Comment: It looks like you have three questions. The first question: [How to generate RSA private key using OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5927164/608639) The second question is at [Programmatically Create X509 Certificate using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/256405/608639). The third question, save as PKCS#8, just uses [`i2d_RSAPrivateKey_bio`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/i2d_RSAPrivateKey_bio.html). An example of writing in all the formats is also given at [How to generate RSA private key using OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30493975/608639)

Comment: You should ask a separate question for the SAML signature. You need to provide your data, and show your code.

Comment: @jww i don't have three question i only have one the rest u mentionned in your comment about certificates i know how to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate RSA private key using OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927164/how-to-generate-rsa-private-key-using-openssl)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You can generate a public-private keypair with the `genrsa` context (the last number is the keylength in bits):

```
openssl genrsa -out keypair.pem 2048
```

To extract the public part, use the `rsa` context:

```
openssl rsa -in keypair.pem -pubout -out publickey.crt
```

Finally, convert the original keypair to PKCS#8 format with the `pkcs8` context:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -nocrypt -in keypair.pem -out pkcs8.key
```

Comment: `keypair.pem` is identical to `pkcs8.key`.  No need for 3rd command. Just make sure you name your private key what you want in the first command, then run the second command to generate your public key.

Comment: @ubiquibacon keypair.pem is in PKCS1 format, the third command converts it to PKCS8. So while the key is the same, the format is not. That's at least the behaviour of LibreSSL 3.3.6. Details and examples in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48960291/759042.