# Correctly generating certificates for JWT in Java

Tags: openssl, rsa, x509, jwt

I am trying to use the simple example given here:

https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt

```
//HMAC
Algorithm algorithmHS = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret");

//RSA
RSAPublicKey publicKey = //Get the key instance
RSAPrivateKey privateKey = //Get the key instance
Algorithm algorithmRS = Algorithm.RSA256(publicKey, privateKey);
```

Unfortunately getting the key instances for public and private key is not that simple.

1. I followed [How to create public and private key with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474516/how-to-create-public-and-private-key-with-openssl) to generate public and private key.
2. I converted private key to the DER form `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in private_key.pem -out pkcs8.der -nocrypt`
3. Now I am able to load the private key as:

   ```
   val privateKey = readKeyAsBytes("pkcs8.der")
           .run { PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(this) }
           .run { KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(this) }
           as RSAPrivateKey
   ```
4. However this doesn't work for generating the public key:

   ```
   val publicKey = readKeyAsBytes("publickey.crt")
           .run { X509EncodedKeySpec(this) }
           .run { KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(this) }
           as RSAPublicKey
   ```

as it fails with `InvalidKeyException: invalid key format`. I am not sure whether `.getInstnace(RSA)` is correct here, but I couldn't make it work with anything else either. I guess the public key is not in the X509 format, but I cannot seem to manage to convert it to it.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you converted the private key file 'private_key.pem', to a DER format, but did you also convert the public key to a DER format.

The readKeyAsBytes function is expecting binary data.

DER stands for Distinguished encoding rules; it is a binary format.  PEM is just a base64 encoded representation of the DER binary data with a header before and a footer after.  But it is ascii text not binary.

If you open the files with a text editor, the DER file will be a bunch of crazy unreadable stuff.

The PEM files will look something like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
MIIGuzCCBaOgAwIBAgIUT2q/veSq2N3hq+1QSqfrZo6SW8IwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL 
...
Wu/svFTqcFBje8FiO98kFwJwSuajwt9l2mToy7W7PkQ+WARIOLR/7pcNh27O99Y=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Good luck